# why .on can't be used in my $(document).ready() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page can be viewed at

http://cistrome.org/cps/seqconfig?did=2693

When load in Firebugs, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: $(".open_gene").on is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$(".open_gene").on('change', function(event) {
```

However, if I type in this expression in Firebug's console, it can be evaluated as a function without any problems:

```
>>> $(".open_gene").on
function()
```

I was wondering what might be the reason to cause this issue.
Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running? If it's older than 1.7, `.on()` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is available from jQuery v1.7 you have version 1.6.4 in your site

EDIT

In your html you load version 1.6.4 then later on you load version 1.7.2 in javascript, but your bindingssites.js loads before version 1.7.2 so `.on()` is not available at the time but is later in the console. I'd suggest putting your jquery fallback loader right after the first jQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function check_jquery() {
        //console.log('jquery');
        var jquery = window.$ || window.JQuery;
        //console.log('jquery: '+(jquery?(jquery.fn?jquery.fn.jquery:'null'):'null'));
        if (jquery === undefined || jquery.fn.jquery !== '1.7.2') {
            mygene.loadfile(mygene.url_root + 'js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', 'js', check_jquery_ui);
            //console.log('jquery: loaded');
        } else {
            check_jquery_ui();
        }

    };
    check_jquery();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,Musa! Another question is  why  I can use `.on()` without any problem in `firebug`? Does firebug have newest `jquery` built-in?

Comment: Because by the time you do that, jquery 1.7 is loaded from http://mygene.info/widget/autocomplete/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js.  You are loading two versions of jquery.

Comment: The inline JavaScript does an asynchronous load of jQuery 1.7 so processing continues before it is loaded but then it is available by the time the console is used.

Answer (score 2):

You're loading a very old version of jQuery (1.6.4). `on()` wasn't added until 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading two versions of jQuery: 1.6.4 and 1.7.2. You're loading 1.7.2 after 1.6.4.

In the context where it's failing it's using 1.6.4 but later when you open up Firebug it's using the later-loaded 1.7.2.